# Positioning a header without moving rest of page down

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am new to CSS and I am trying to position my header literally a few pixels down without moving the rest of the page down.

I have tried `padding-bottom` but it moves the page down, tried margin bottom and it does nothing. 
Tried floating, aligning. Line height has no effect for some reason. The only thing that has a slight effect is `position: absolute;` and `line-height` worked in conjunction with that however it moved it just a little too far down and now i need it just a few pixels higher. The `line-height` will not raise any more than 2px and I have also tried using a % in all the above.

Does anyone have a solution to the issue before I used position:absolute an also the issue I have now with `line-height` restrictions.

```
h2 {
    padding-left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that position: absolute will cause you some issues. This is because you are taking it out of the regular flow, so it will not keep its place anymore. If you run into issues, try position: relative instead. That should keep it in the flow, and combined with top: 2px should shift it downards a bit.

Some other options you can also try include margin-top: 2px or padding-top:2px (while using position:relative). The reason why padding-bottom didn't work was because you were adding some extra "padding"/space below it, rather than above it.

Does this make sense? Please ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute` adding margin won't affect position.

Try using `top: 2px` it will position the element 2 pixels down from the top. Also `line-height: 2px` looks pretty hacky, unless the font-size is 1px I wouldn't use it.

```
h2 {
    padding-left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}
```

More about position property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: boom!  you've just hit the 1K mark, you're welcome :)